# how to refresh a partial after an edit has been made in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making an ecommerce website page.It consists of two parts.A sidebar having a list of all products and a right column where the details of the product is shown once the product is selected from the list.

I am making ajax calls to load the various partials of the application. The sidebar having all the products is index,the one on right having the details of products is show which shows the details of the product selected.
Now when I edit the product(through a modal) how do I automatically reload the respective partials so that the new changes are reflecte.For me to see the changes I have to refresh the pages currently,how do i ensure the partials are automatically loaded once I click submit on the edit modal.

My index.html.erb looks like

```
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
           <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
            <div class="well sidebar-nav">
              <ul class="nav">
                <div class="jumbotron well">
      <h3>Product Listing Application</h3>
               </div>

                  <%= link_to "New Product", new_product_path, remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary" %>

                <div class="list-group">
                  <%= render "index" %>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </div><!--/.well -->
          </div><!--/span-->   

          <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-8">
         <div id="page-content-wrapper">
<div class="page-content">
<div class="col-md-12 product-info" id="product-details">

</div>
</div>
</div>
          <div id="product-modal" class="modal fade"></div>
      </div>

        </div><!--/row-->
  </div>
```

My _index.html.erb is

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
     <%= link_to product_path(product), remote: true, class: "list-group-item"  do %> 
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><%= product.name %></h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text"><%= number_to_currency product.price %></p>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

My _edit.html.erb is

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
  <h3><%= "Editing #{@product.name}" %></h3>
</div>
<%= render "form" %>
</div>
</div>
```

My _form.html.erb is

```
<%= form_for @product, remote: true, html: { class: "form-horizontal", style: "display:inline;" } do |f| %>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <ul class="errors"></ul>

    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :name, class:"control-label" %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :price, class: "control-label" %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= f.text_field :price %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <%= link_to "Cancel", "#", class: "btn", data: {dismiss: "modal"} %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
location.reload();
```

on your js.erb for refresh your partial, or for your instance vaiable
you can directly use

```
@post = @post.reload # in palce of @post you can your instance variable
```

Comment: That will issue a reload of the entire page, in case anyone's wondering.

Answer (score 0):

create a js file same name as your page 
add below code in it

edit.js.erb

```
$("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'ur_partial_page_name')  %>").dialog();
$('#new_comment_link').hide();`
```

in your edit page form where u r calling modal dialog

```
<%= link_to "edit", edit_product_path (@product, :format => :js), :remote => true %>
```

In your product controller

```
def edit  
    @source = Product.find(params[:id])  
    respond_to do |format|  
        format.html # edit.html.erb  
        format.xml  { render :xml => @product }  
        format.js  
    end  
end
```

and in your partial form

```
<%= form_for (@product, :remote => true) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Would you mind formatting your answer properly? Also, you could fix the grammar. "Your" instead of "ur", "You are" instead of "U r" etc.

Comment: No, I'm not. Use indendation instead of `.